# как сделать так, чтобы можно было вводить число в браузере и браузер выдавал булевское значение?

Tags: javascript

```js
function number(num){
  var chislo;
  chislo=num;
  if (chislo%2==0){
   console.log(true);
  }else if (!chislo%2==0){
   console.log(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, отформатируйте код и дополните вопрос описанием преобразования из числа в булев тип. Лучше добавить примеры для тестов

Answer (score 1):

А зачем писать if-else, если выражение само по себе принимает значения true / false ?)

```js
function isEven(num){
  return num % 2 == 0;
}

console.log( isEven(14) ); // true
console.log( isEven(17) ); // false

// console.log( isEven( +prompt("Введите число") ) ); ← плюсик превращает строку в число
```

Или `return !( num % 2 );` — если `num % 2` возвращает 0 (четное число) - ноль в логическом контексте будет false. А нужен true, поэтому использовано логическое НЕ`!`

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужна функция, возвращающая true, когда число четное:

```js
function bool(num) {
  return !(num % 2)
}

console.log(bool(2));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var b = prompt("введите число");
var a = [true, false];
if (b == 1) {
    console.log(a[0]);
} else {
    console.log(a[1]);
}
```

Comment: этот код делает совсем не то, что нужно.